# jinja2 - ampersand in a if else code block

Tags: python, jinja2

I am looking to make a determination if two lists have common elements.

This works in Python

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = [3,4,5]
set(listA) & set(listB)
set([3])
```

But in jinja2

```
{% set listA=[1,2,3] %}
{% set listB=[3,4,5] %}
{% if set(listA) & set(listB) %}
# Do something
{% endif %}
```

Jinja complains: *Jinja syntax error: unexpected char u'&'*

Comment: You can always do `{% if set(listA).union(set(listB)) %}`

Comment: vaultah, thanks for the clue.